# Bulk rename files using part of existing filename

Tags: windows, file, cmd, zip, rename

New to StackOverflow (posting), not new to it saving me on countless occasions. Unfortunately I can't find the information to point me in the right direction this time.

Every day, I receive a zip file containing multiple filenames. I need a way to, each day, rename each file using part of the existing filename, and the current date. So the files will go from:

Example -

```
thisisjust_atest.pdf
another_test.pdf
just_anothertest.pdf
yayone_moretest.pdf
```

to

```
atest - 2018-02-13.pdf
test - 2018-02-13.pdf
anothertest - 2018-02-13.pdf
moretest - 2018-02-13.pdf
```

I'd plan to do this somehow via a VB script so it could send the files via e-mail after sorting them out, but this is only because I don't have much experience in anything else. Happy to be pointed in the right direction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Wich OS are you running ? I guess windows as far as you're talking about VB script

Comment: Hi, Running Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM get date in desired format:
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value') do set "today=%%I"
set "today=%today:~0,4%-%today:~4,2%-%today:~6,2%"

REM for every matching file...
for %%A in (*_*.pdf) do (
  REM ...get desired part...
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%B in ("%%~nA") do (
    REM ... and add datestring:
    ECHO ren "%%A" "%%B - %today%%%~xA"
  )
)
```

Note: remove the `ECHO`, if the output is exactly, what you want.

Comment: Thanks, we managed to adapt the code to do what we need. Thanks again, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward in PowerShell. Use a regex to get the desired part of the existing name. Then, concatenate the current date to get the new filename.

When you are confident that the renames are being done correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` cmdlet.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf -File |
    ForEach-Object {
        $newbase = $_.Name -replace '.*_([^_]*)\.pdf','$1'
        $newname = "$newbase - $(Get-Date -UFormat %Y-%m-%d).pdf"
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newname -WhatIf
    }
```

Note that this does not take care of the problem if duplicate names are created by removing the first part of the name.

Note that this will work even if the original filename contains multiple underscore characters.

If you must run this from a cmd.exe shell (.bat file), then put the PowerShell code into a file such as renamenews.ps1. Then invoke it using:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File renamenews.ps1
```